# MySQL Galera cluster can't initiate first node

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, galera

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and installed MySQL version 5.7 via `apt-get` in AWS.

After that, I've managed to upgrade the MySQL to Galera Cluster by following the Documentation from the [official website](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/installmysql.html) using `apt-get install galera-3 galera-arbitrator-3 mysql-wsrep-5.6`

After that I've configured the file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf` to be:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://this_node_ip,second_ip,third_ip"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="this_node_ip"
wsrep_node_name="this_node_name"
```

The step above is repeated for the other 2 nodes (with it's own IP address). And stop the mysql with the following command `sudo service mysql stop` for each of the node.

And in the first node, I'm trying to start with the following command:

```
sudo service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
```

But it returns: `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

In the `systemctl status mysql.service`, it says:

```
● mysql.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-09 15:53:16 +08; 33s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6264 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 09 15:53:15 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Feb 09 15:53:15 mysql[6264]: Starting MySQL
Feb 09 15:53:15 mysql[6264]: .180209 15:53:15 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
Feb 09 15:53:15 mysql[6264]: 180209 15:53:15 mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
Feb 09 15:53:16 mysql[6264]:  * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).
Feb 09 15:53:16 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 09 15:53:16 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
Feb 09 15:53:16 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 09 15:53:16 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Hope these information helps.

Comment: `mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.` isn't that obvious enough what is problem? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysqld_safe-can-t-log-to-error-log-and-syslog-at-the-same-time

Comment: Did you ever get this issue solved? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: Yeah. I used mariaDB straight away, it comes with Galera. Work out of the box. There is something wrong with the wsrep above if you install MySQL and Galera seperately.